# how can we install Magento on AWS?

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, aws

I am new to amazon web services.And I want to install Magento 1.9.1.1 on it.Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: I want to integrate my Magento based website on the AWS Cloud. I've scanned through the FAQ and the installation pdf thoroughly, but I'm still a bit confused about getting the CloudFormation finished. Everything seems to be fine except that 2 of 3 stacks still CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. Any ideas maybe on how to fix this? Another question I have is whether they have a related module or service of some sorts to backup my files and database to AWS Cloud with fewer clicks? The website uses the Ketty Store theme from [http://www.templatemonster.com/magento-themes.php](http://www.templatemonster.com/magen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [link](http://www.comtechies.com/2014/03/how-to-install-magento-on-amazon-ec2.html) maybe help in your condition.

1. Launch an Ubuntu instance using the management console. When launching the instance , make sure you open port 80 in the security groups.

   2. Connect the instance using putty.
   3. Login as root user.

   sudo su

   4. Update the server

Install LAMP stack:
Magento backend need apache , Php and Mysql database. You can configure all three applications using one command.

1. Install and configure Lamp stack.

apt-get install  -y lamp-server^

2. Create a root password for mysql and confirm it.
3. You can check if apache and mysql service is running using the following commands

service apache2 status
service mysql status

4. Magento needs a database on mysql server. You can create a databse on mysql server using command line and phpmyadmin. I prefer phpmyadmin, since you can manage your mysql server from the browser using GUI.
5. Install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu instance

apt-get install phpmyadmin

You will be prompted to select the webserver. Select apache using the space bar and hit enter. Then you will be prompted to enter the phpmyadmin root password. Give a strong password.

Phpmyadmin has to be integrated with mysql-server. So when prompted select db-conf and enter the mysql root password you created during the LAMP stack installation.

6. Once installed, you can access the phpmyadmin dashboard using the public ip, elastic ip or the Public dns of your instance followed by /phpmyadin.

54.154.35.67/phpmyadmin

1. Login to phpmyadmin using the credentials you created . The defatult username is root and password is the password you created during phpmyadmin setup.
2. Create a database magentoDB for magento application using phpmyadmin.
3. Click the database option in the top navigation panel and enter magentodb for the database name and hit enter.

Download Magento
1. Download magento to the /var/www folder.

wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.8.1.0/magento-1.8.1.0.tar.gz

2. Untar the file

tar –xvzf mag*

3. Change the file permissions for the following folders to give Magento write permission on those folders.

chmod -R o+w magento/app/etc/
chmod -R o+w magento/var/
chmod -R o+w magento/media/

4. Add mcrypt extension to the php.ini file located in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

vi  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
extension=mcrypt.so

5. Install php5 curl.

apt-get install php5-curl

6. Add curl extension to the php.ini file.

vi  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Extension=curl.so

Installing Magento stack:
1. Go to http:// /magento from your browser. Magento installation wizard will appear.

eg : http://54.23.154.34/magento

2. Tick the terms and conditions and hit continue.

apt-get update

Comment: I don't think this is the proper way to work with the "Cloud" in general. If you want to work with AWS, you want to have all the benefits, like autoscaling, immutability, self-healing and so on. The answer you give only describes the installation of Magento on a Server. To install Magento within AWS as it is recommended, you should set up your AWS resources as recommended in the AWS Reference Architecture here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/magento/architecture.html

Answer (score 0):

This doc from AWS itself has a very thorough walkthrough and a lot of useful information on what you're setting up and how to do it properly, securely, and using best practices on AWS.

**From the AWS Quick Start Overview**

> The Quick Start includes a deployment guide that describes the Magento
>   architecture on AWS, provides step-by-step instructions for deploying
>   and configuring the software, and discusses design and performance
>   considerations.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/magento/welcome.html

Answer (score -1):

**Here are the steps:**

1. First, create instance of ec2
2. Generate elastic ip from network and security.
3. Assign elastic ip to instance
4. Generate pem file
5. Convert it to ppk file using puttygen.
6. Generate and get Privatekey
7. Start putty -> default pwd is : ubuntu
8. Enter elastic ip to connect server using putty
9. Connectivity -> ssh - > auth -> give ppk file path

You should be able to connect to the Amazon server now.

Now follow this link to install Apache, Php and MySQL

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04

Here are some useful articles we have followed to set up Magento on amazon

http://www.inkthemes.com/how-to-install-wordpress-on-amazon-aws-ec2/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

http://www.inkthemes.com/how-to-install-wordpress-on-amazon-aws-ec2/

**create ftp :**

http://quadloops.com/blog/installing-up-ftp-server-in-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server-12-04/

Comment: You shouldn't use static IP's. A bastion or JumpHost would be the better alternative. This is way more secure and follows best practices. There is also no use case for installing a single ec2 instance. You should also move your application into an immutable state and launch it in an autoscaling group.